# Django - confirmation with jquery bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to make my confirmation looks better, but when I'm trying to do it it's not working properly.

it shows me everything fine but it automatically click "ok" by itself, not letting me if I want to confirm or not.

Here's what I got:

my template:

```
<td > <a href="{% url 'edit' item.id %}" class="confirm" > <img class="autoResizeImage" src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/edit-icon-1901.png"/ > </a>  </td>
```

My js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.confirm', function(){
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result){ alert('This was logged in the callback: ' + result); });
```

**Note:**

Only happens if I add my `<a href="{% url 'edit' item.id %}"></a>` if I have something simple like this `<button class="confirm" > click me </button>` works great.

What am I doing wrong?

Basically after I hit "edit" to make my `onclick jquery function` appears my confirmation but it automatically redirects me to my `<a href="{% url 'edit' item.id %}"></a>` and I want to redirect me when I hit "ok" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent your `click` event from triiggering the anchor as well as its propagation if your bootbox has click handler up the DOM treee , you might try

```
$(document).on('click', '.confirm', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result){ 
      alert('This was logged in the callback: ' + result); 
    });
    //rest of the code for this click
});
```